# ImageButton changing color of the image

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We are using Xamarin.Forms with Xamarin.Forms.Labs components for the ImageButton. This is iOS.

For some reason the ImageButton is changing the color of the image that we want to use in the control. The standard Button component does the same, however, the Image componet works fine.

In the image, you can see how we load the same file into an Image, ImageButton, and Button views, and you can see that the Image one is correct, but the other two are changed from red to blue.

Any idea how to make the ImageButton or Button component show the original image without altering the colors?.

Snippet:

```
        // wrong colors
        var addPins = new ImageButton() {
            Image = (FileImageSource) ImageSource.FromFile("Marker.png"),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            ImageHeightRequest = 50,
            ImageWidthRequest = 50,
            HeightRequest = 50,
            WidthRequest = 50
        };

        // good colors
        var addPins2 = new Image { 
            Source = ImageSource.FromFile ("Marker.png"),
            HeightRequest = 50,
            WidthRequest = 50,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        // wrong colors
        var addPins3 = new Button  { 
            Image = new FileImageSource { File = "Marker.png"} ,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HeightRequest = 50,
            WidthRequest = 50
        };

        grid.Children.Add (addPins, 1, 2); 
        grid.Children.Add (addPins2, 1, 1); 
        grid.Children.Add (addPins3, 1, 0);
```

Sample result:

[image: Sample]

Comment: Yeah it's a bug in the ImageButton of Labs, can you open a issue on github please? 

You can take the source code for the iOS renderer and create your ExtendedImageButton, and fix the problem.

A funky workaround is to create your "ContentButton", take a content view, add a grid to it, than add a button with clear background and no text, and also add the image your want. Expose the click even on your content view, and use it like it was a button.

Comment: Issue created. https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/465. Thanks for the workaround - I think I'll wait (I am just starting a project that will take months, hopefully the bug gets corrected by then).

Comment: Created Xamarin bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24345